# Increment file name and create a new version of the file

Tags: saving, filenames

Assume that I am working with a file whose name contains a unique version number for example `myfile_03.tex` or `03jhcjh.tex` and so on. Currently I create a new version of the file by `C-x C-w` and incrementing the number manually.

To be precise I would like to maintain the number length if possible, i.e. 027 → 028 instead of 28, but 9 → 10.

Is there a function in emacs which automatizes this procedure? Other solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

The following elisp code should define a function `write-file-increment` doing what you want, except for the "preserving length" part.

If the file name does not contain a number, it adds "-1". Apart from that case, the position of the number in the filename shouldn't matter.

```
(defun tv/increment-number-in-file-name (name)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert name)
    (search-backward "." nil t)
    (re-search-backward "[0-9]+" nil t)
    ;(skip-chars-forward "0") ;; Would preserve 0s
    (if (looking-at "[0123456789]+")
        (replace-match (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0)))))
      (insert "-1"))
    (buffer-string)))

(defun write-file-increment ()
  (interactive)
  (write-file (tv/increment-number-in-file-name (buffer-file-name))))
```

Preserving prefixed `0`s can be done by uncommenting the commented line, but it would also replace `09` with `010`, probably not what you want.

Comment: I suggest to add `(re-search-backward "[0-9]+" nil t)` before `(skip-chars-backward "0123456789")` otherwise `31_file.tex` becomes `31_file-1.tex`.

Comment: @Name Indeed that's a possibility. I tend to think this kind of numbering is best placed at the end of the name, for sorting purposes, but one of the examples of the question does have the numbering at the start. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Btw `aaa31bbb22.txt` will still become `aaa31bbb23.txt`, there's not much I can suggest short of creating an ad-hoc function for this usecase if you want to increment `31` instead.

Comment: In my question, I have assumed that there is a unique identifiable number in the file name. Sorry if I have worded it badly.

Comment: hi. i get this error when i try to run the function ``progn: Search failed: "."Invalid face reference: quote``. any clue? also can one also stick current date in the generated file name?

Comment: @zeltak Your file name didn't contain a dot, is it correct? If so, I think the new version is fixed. For the date, sure it would be possible, but that's going out of the scope of the question.

Comment: works great now,thx! should i open another Q for the addition of current date?i would love to have that added to the above function!

Answer (score -1):

`C-x C-f <your directory>
wdired-change-to-wdired-mode
query-replace-regexp`

Using `query-replace-regexp` with `\#` should do.

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you elaborated a bit, such as showing a step-by-step example, addressing the example(s) used in the question.